# Justify texts to the entire line

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to create a receipt with iText.
for example:

```
String1 = "Sale Amount"
String2 = "$2.00"
```

the purpose is how to justift the 2 Strings to the PDF Line and then I get:

```
  ------------------------------------
  | Sale Amount                $2.00 |
```

Sale Amount to the Left  and  $2.00 to the Right.

Comment: *"Thx"*  This is not a text message, so it seems not too much trouble to type ***all 6*** letters of words like 'thanks'.  But you can leave such noise out of posts entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download [chapter 2](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) of my book and start reading the section "SEPARATOR CHUNKS" on page 44. A separator chunk is a special `Chunk` instance that acts the same way as "Glue" in Java. It is typically used to separate a title from a page number by a dotted line in a Table of Contents, but you can also use it without the dotted line to achieve the kind of alignment you need.

An alternative would be that you create a table with two columns and adapted cell borders. You'd then define the alignment of the cells in the first column as left aligned, and the alignment of the cells in the second column as right aligned. The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to define column widths (do you know what to expect?) and that you need to write more code. The advantage is that the content will wrap correctly if it doesn't fit on one line.

Comment: thank you for response, but is it possible to do it with tables? I don't know how, but I'm searching now in this way.

Comment: I've edited my answer, assuming that you mean that you want to have the text in one column and the actual amount in the other.

Comment: thanks, I opted for this alternative (table solution) and I used cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); to clear table border